# eslint Plugin "react" was conflicted between

Tags: reactjs, windows, npm, eslint

Estoy haciendo una app en react, al escribri el comando

```
npm start
```

abre el `localhost:3000` y se ve el

> Edit src/App.js and save to reload pero sucede que también me sale
> este error:

```
Failed to compile.

[eslint] Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » C:\Users\Emily Gelvez\desktop\tabulador\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » C:\Users\Emily Gelvez\Desktop\tabulador\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".
ERROR in [eslint] Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » C:\Users\Emily Gelvez\desktop\tabulador\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » C:\Users\Emily Gelvez\Desktop\tabulador\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

¿Eso afectaría en algo a mi proyecto?

Este es mi archivo `node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js`

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */

'use strict';

// Fix eslint shareable config (https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/3458)
require('@rushstack/eslint-patch/modern-module-resolution');

// This file contains the minimum ESLint configuration required for Create
// React App support, and is used as the `baseConfig` for `eslint-loader`
// to ensure that user-provided configs don't need this boilerplate.

module.exports = {
  root: true,

  parser: '@babel/eslint-parser',

  plugins: ['react'],

  env: {
    browser: true,
    commonjs: true,
    es6: true,
    jest: true,
    node: true,
  },

  parserOptions: {
    sourceType: 'module',
    requireConfigFile: false,
    babelOptions: {
      presets: [require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/prod')],
    },
  },

  settings: {
    react: {
      version: 'detect',
    },
  },

  rules: {
    'react/jsx-uses-vars': 'warn',
    'react/jsx-uses-react': 'warn',
  },
};
```

este es mi archivo `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "tabulador",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.47.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "stylelint": "^15.10.3",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^34.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3"
  }
}
```

Quiero saber si puedo continuar normal o eso afectaría en algo o como solucionar ese error, gracias.

Comment: ¿Tienes una carpeta desktop y una carpeta Desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Ese error por el momento quizás no te llegue afectar, pero al largo plazo muy posiblemente si lo haga.
Para tratar de solucionarlo podrías borrar el node-modules y el package-lock.json, y luego ejecutat npm install. En caso de que esto no te funcione, te recomendaría migrar el proyecto a uno nuevo, es lo que me ha funcionado en lo personal.